# Change ConEmu's default start directory

Tags: conemu, working-directory

How do I change ConEmu settings such that always when I open it, it will start the cmd in a directory of my choosing instead of the default ConEmu folder?

Comment: An alt solution is to put some batch jobs somewhere in your path that just `cd X:\Some\Long\Directory\Name` for dirs that you commonly use. That way you're not limited to one dir, you're not limited to conemu, and you're not limited to just at startup.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In addition to the answer by Bruno Pereira.

1) Another way - create new task with "cmd" in Commands (if not already created) and add following into "Gui args" field of task properties, **and** choose this task on startup page (radio "Specified named task")

```
/dir "FullPathToDir"
```

[image]
[image]

2) One more example - run shell like (Startup -> Command line)

```
cmd "-cur_console:d:C:\Users\Maks"
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that tasks don't run when I start conemu.

Comment: Not true. You may choose any named task for startup on "Startup" page.

Comment: I get a command group is empty! error when I add the /dir PATH to task parameters

Comment: So? You get a message from program. Why not to make it "not empty"? Add "cmd" to the task command. PS. If message is not clear - suggest your own text.

Comment: I don't understand anything. Your app is excellent but you need to improve the english labels and the GUI usability. With Console2 I just need to go to Edit->Settings and edit the "Startup dir" field, that's all. I'm going to upvote the other answer (and if I could I'd downvote yours), in 2 secs I've changed the startup dir, with your steps is IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas If you read my steps CAREFULLY and realize them one-by-one - your task will be completed. No changes was made to the answer, just screenshot was added. "Specially for..."

Comment: Second approach is much better as it's simpler and doesn't open PowerShell!

Comment: I wanted to have Git Bash open in a default directory on load, and to be able to open a new tab with *those same settings* by simply clicking the plus icon. Combining the first part of this answer from Maximus and Bruno Pereira's solution below I was able to achieve this.

Comment: For me, the /dir option didn't work for me, until I released that the option `-new_console:d:"%USERPROFILE%"` was part of the commands thus overriding my /dir selection.

Comment: Just to have in mind, that the **Task parameters** are in the conEmu format, so even if you set it up for bash you need to use the same **dir "C:\"** syntax

Comment: Way more confusing than it should be for such a simple need.

Answer (score 45):

Just edit your startup shortcut adding the `/Dir` option as such:

```
ConEmu /Dir <path to desired directory>
```

Or on the shortcut properties change the *Start in:* path to something that fancies you

[image]

Comment: I don't know why the above one has more upvotes. This is the correct way to change the "default" start directory, as requested. This will apply to *all* tasks started in that ConEmu instance.

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all though.

Comment: Found the culprit - I was invoking bash with `-login` option, and that would always result in home directory. Now setting up directories with `-cur_console` or `-new_console` works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Open settings:

1. Startup/Tasks
2. Create new task
3. In the first box put a name, e.g. `Console`
4. In the third box copy this: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  -cur_console:d:D:/`
5. Go to Startup and select the task from the "specified named task" menu.

Restart

Comment: how do I write a folder path which contains space?

Comment: have you tried to quote the path with `"` ?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. Create a task and execute it when ConEmu starts.

**Create task**, e.g. go to folder `D:\exampleDir`

You can concatenate commands using `&`

[image: Task creation - ConEmu]

**Execute task** on startup:

[image: Task on startup - ConEmu]

Answer (score 1):

In the task window, as in the top answer, use the following:

```
/dir %HOMEPATH%
```

instead of a direct path to your home folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `/dir` thing didn't work for me with Powershell. I ended up putting the command as `powershell.exe -noexit D:\MyDocs` like so:

[image: Powershell with default directory]

and then set that to be the Startup task as already demonstrated in Maximus' answer:

[image: No]

Answer (score 1):

Another real easy way that worked for me was to open up the Properties of the ConEmu shortcut (in Windows) and then edit the "Start in:"  field as shown in the image below.

[conemu shortcut properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aII6Q.png)
[image]