# How do I configure ConEmu to run Cygwin Bash?

Tags: windows-7, bash, cygwin, conemu

I created a new task

> {Bash}

passed my home directory

> /dir "C:\Users\TMB\"

and added bash as an application

> C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe

When I open Bash, it is unable to use the basic UNIX/Cygwin utilities.  How do I configure ConEmu to run Cygwin Bash?

Comment: What ConEmu version you are trying? Also, not all bash versions supports working directory. Git bash - can, as I remember.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to set me working directory in my bash profile, but I think I found a more general solution below the marked answer.

Comment: ConEmu x64 120727c.x64

Comment: With "working directory" I mean one you specify with /dir switch. BTW, have you read this answer? http://superuser.com/a/482340/139371

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This might helps others.

It looks like version 140310 of ConEmu automatically detects CygWin Bash.

If you've installed Cygwin after you installed ConEmu, you'll need to **Reload...** your list of Tasks.

1. Go to **Settings... (Win + Alt + P)**
2. Navigate to your list of **Tasks (Startup > Tasks)**
3. Click on the **Reload...** button.

You should now see **{CygWin bash}** as one of your options in the list of predefined tasks:

[image: Screenshot of CygWin bash in ConEmu]

*PS -- If this method doesn't work, try resetting your ConEmu settings (click the **Reset...** button at the bottom of your **Settings** window).*

Comment: And if **Reloading** and **Resetting** don't work, I guess we could enter the path, command, and options as shown in your screen shot.

Comment: `%SystemDrive%\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe --login -i` for me on **140304** on the Preview Channel.

Comment: For me clicking the `Add default tasks...` button (right above the `Reload` button) did the trick...

Comment: Note that sh.exe won't source your .bashrc; only bash.exe will do that. So I'm using the command `%SystemDrive%\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i`

Comment: @JohnPrior's comment is actually very helpful. The PATH variable was all wrong when using sh.exe, but with bash.exe it can now actually find my applications.

Comment: I found that if I wanted to have the default tab start bash, I had to select the `{Bash}` task on the *Startup* settings (one level above *Tasks*).

Answer (score 7):

or instead of

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
```

use

```
C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat
```

Comment: I think that's indeed the simplest way.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that Bash is receiving a sensible value for `$PATH`; usually it inherits that from whatever calls it, but ConEmu is a Windows application, so all it's going to provide is whatever you have set for `%Path%`. Generally that doesn't include the Cygwin path directories, so Bash doesn't know where to look for `ls`, &c.

The way I'd solve this would be to, via whatever means ConEmu offers for doing so, pass `--login -i` as command line arguments to Bash; this will tell it you're running it as an interactive login shell, so it will read `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bashrc` on start. In my experience, that's been enough to give it a sensible `$PATH`; if that doesn't work for you, you could specify it explicitly with a line like `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:[...]:$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: This got me the utilities I was looking for next I wanted to point to my normal windows home directory not `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home` so I deleted `home` and made a junction with `mklink -J home C:\Users` in cmd.exe

Comment: Glad it did the job for you. I never thought about using a junction to point ~ at c:\users\me, but I once did it with a symlink, and from that experience I give you the following warning: if you ever need to run ComboFix to clean up a malware infestation on your machine, **it will blow away any files in c:\users\you**. I lost everything in my home directory that way once, and my newest backup was a week old. Don't make the same mistake I did!

Answer (score 2):

This is my way

Create a new task in ConEmu with following command

```
set HOME=C:\Home & "C:\Home\Applications\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe" -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

Comment: Your solution works, and I like having the mintty.exe interface, but can you explain why this works? Especially, what is the "&" doing here?

Answer (score 0):

I know thats a pretty old question but I wanted to share this anyway:

To start the bash within a specific working directory just set the command for example to `SET CHERE_INVOKING=1 & "C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i" -cur_console:t:"cygwin terminal"` and specify the working directory normally via `/dir "..."` as described [here](http://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartDir.html).

Answer (score 0):

To make Cygwin commands available from `bash`, regardless of how you run it, as well as from `cmd` or any other shell, make sure your `Path` environment variable has Cygwin's `bin` directory added.
Go to `Control Panel > System and Security > System` (standard hotkey `Win+Pause`), then `Advanced system settings > Environment variables`. For all users, edit the system `Path` variable, just for your user - edit (create if it doesn't exist) the user `Path` variable.
Assuming `cygwin` is installed at `C:\cygwin` (might be cygwin64 for 64-bit Cygwin), add `C:\cygwin\bin` to the `Path`. Be aware that if you use the system `Path` variable, if you add Cygwin's `bin` in the beginning, some Cygwin's command will shadow built-in ones (e.g. Cygwin's `find` will be used instead of Windows' `find`). I prefer to do so, but if you don't, add Cygwin's `bin` at the end of your `Path`.

Since most other answers also talk about ConEmu setup, I'll give my personal opinion as well.

I prefer to run a non-login shell. For example, in Linux you get a login shell when you log in at the text console or via ssh, and a non-login interactive shell when you open a terminal emulator (xterm, konsole, etc.).

My {Bash} task has `/dir "%CD%"` task parameters to set the working directory to the current tab's working directory (e.g. if the bash task from Far). The command to start bash:
`%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin\Cygwin.ico"`

Notice `--login -i` options are omitted, shell will start as a non-login interactive shell (since it has no non-option arguments and without the -c option, and it's stdin and stdout are connected to terminals, refer to INVOCATION section of bash's manpage for more explanation). It will read and execute commands from the user rcfile `~/.bashrc` (not `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile` as a login shell would, thus you don't need to `set CHERE_INVOKING=1` which is only relevant with regards to `/etc/profile`). So put your user aliases, shell options, extra environment variables etc. to ~/.bashrc, where they rightfully belong.