# Configure Powershell to be conemu's default shell

Tags: windows, powershell, conemu

Is it possible to configure Powershell to be conemu's default shell?

I know I can add additional "tasks" to conemu but I want it to default to use Powershell instead of cmd.exe so that, for example, when I use a plugin for an IDE that opens conemu in the current working directory, it does so with a conemu-wrapped Powershell instance.

Comment: Choose PowerShell on "Startup" page of Settings dialog.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Assuming a "{Powershell}" task:

[image]

Use the Startup tab and assign Powershell under "Specified named task":

[image]

If you want to start in a specific directory, change the task definition like so:

[image: Powershell with default directory]

Comment: setting default directory as explained above does not work. Try http://superuser.com/questions/482325/change-conemus-default-start-directory instead

Comment: @joniba Correct, because powershell takes any strings as a command, so quite literally it's trying to execute `D:\MyDocs`.  The poster needed to specify `-WorkingDirectory`

Comment: Worked for me: `powershell.exe -noexit -Command "cd c:\Users\[Name]\Desktop"`

Answer (score 8):

In recent version there seems to be a setting for this:

[image]

Comment: That setting controls which task populates the ConEmu New Console dialog by default.  The accepted answer is still the correct solution.